# Is data binding in AngularJS based on time period?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I've already read the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/4382683

What I want to know is when does angular decide that it's suitable to run the $digest cycle? Because when I change a property of an object in $scope, it's instantly propagated throughout. Does this dirty-checking happen every 50ms or so?

Also, is Object.watch() used anywhere in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

It's not based on time period. Angular actually `$digest`s only if one of the following happens:

- Any interaction with `ng` tags and attribute or custom directives
- When a promise is resolved. Like for `$http` or `$timeout`

These and probably a few other cases I don't know about. I understand now that it's not possible that the values in `$scope` change without any of these things happening. Hence, whenever these happen, angular does a `$digest`. Also, no time periods.

And, no `Object.watch()` anywhere since it's only for debugging purposes.